# "Launch Flow in Modal" button not appearing for non-admin user

Tags: lightning-apps, flow-screen-component

I have installed "Launch Flow in Modal" in a Sandbox and put it on a custom object record page. However, the button only appears for Admin users, not for non-admin users. The test users' profiles all have the 'Run Flows' permission, and "Launch Flow in Modal" was installed for 'All users'.

Any idea what I am overlooking?

Comment: Double check the [trailhead for running flows](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/flow-testing-and-distribution/enable-user-access) to see if you meet all criteria.

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head against a wall for a long time I suddenly realised that as an administrator I was seeing a slightly different page layout to non-admin users, and I had only added the button to the admin layout. In other words, the reason they couldn't see the button, was because it wasn't there. :-(